# Sticky headers in a UIControllerView inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UIControllerViewController` inside another `UIScrollView`. So far things display fine, but I'd like to implement things so that the `UIControllerViewController`'s header sticks to the top.

I was trying the `UICollectionView` sticky header solution here:
http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using
but couldn't get to work for this case.

My `UIControllerViewController` is generating the header like so:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                             atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ARCollectionHeaderView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        _headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        _headerView.titleLabel.text = self.title;

        reusableview = _headerView;
    }
    return reusableview;
}
```

And the `UIControllerViewController` is added to the `UIScrollView` like so:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[flowLayout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, 60)];

[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, 80)];
_articleList = [[AREmbeddedCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout]];
_articleList.title = @"In Greater Depth";

[_articleList.collectionView registerClass:[ARSimpleCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[self addChildViewController:_articleList];
[self.scrollView addSubview:_articleList.collectionView];
[_articleList didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. Is there a reason you're adding your collection view to another scroll view?

Comment: Yes – the `UIScrollView` contains some additional views separate from the `UICollectionView`.